# Parse.com how to get data that is saved from other device

Tags: android, parse-platform

I've implemented a class called 'donar' in Parse.com and used that in an Android App. I can store and retrieve data from that class without any problem from let us say 'Device 1'.
But the problem is that I'm not getting the data from 'Device 2' and vice versa. 
What could be the problem?

**Code for saving data**

```
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("donar");
                query.whereEqualTo("team_id", team_id);
                query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
                      public void done(int count, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            ParseObject donar = new ParseObject("donar");
                            donar.put("name", name.getText().toString());
                            donar.put("contact", contact.getText().toString());
                            donar.put("nid", nid.getText().toString());

                            donar.saveInBackground();
```

**Code for retrieving data**

```
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("donar");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> donarList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    donars = donarList;
                } else {
                    Log.e("user", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you see the objects in parse web console? Did you try to set callback on `saveInBackground` to see whether these object really get saved?

Comment: I can see the objects in parse web console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Got the solution.

Just comment out these lines in Application class. At least it works for me.

```
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
// Optionally enable public read access.
defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```